# move_uploaded_file(booksPreviews/0.61426800 1565946100.): failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: php, html, form

есть такая форма

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="bookAvatarWrapper">
    <label id="forPreviewe" for="prevHide">Загрузить обложку</label>
    <!-- ДОБАВИТЬ ПРЕВЬЮ -->
    <input type="file" class="hide" id="prevHide" name="addPreview">
    <img src="images/leather_texture404.jpg" id="previeweImg">
  </div>
  <div id="bookAddWrapper">
    <!-- НАЗВАНИЕ -->
    <input name="nameBook" type="text" placeholder="Название книги" class="inputBook"><br><br>
    <!-- ОПИСАНИЕ -->
    <textarea name="descrBook" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Описание вашей книги"></textarea>

    <label id="forAddBookToForm" for="bookHide">Книга</label>
    <!-- КНИГА -->
    <input type="file" class="hide" id="bookHide" name="addBookToForm">
    <!-- ОК -->
    <input type="submit" value="Ок" id="addNewBook" class="inputBook" name="doneNewBook">
  </div>
</form>
```

```
  if(isset($_POST['doneNewBook'])){
    $bookPreview = $_FILES['addPreview'];
    $bookName = $_POST['nameBook'];
    $bookDescr = $_POST['descrBook'];
    $uploadBook = $_FILES['addBookToForm'];

    if(isSecurityBook($uploadBook)){
        if (isSecurityPrev($bookPreview)) {
            $typeBook = $bookPreview['type'];
            $uploaddirBook = "books/";
            $nameBook = md5(microtime()).".".substr($type, strlen("text/"));
            $uploadfileBook = $uploaddirBook.$nameBook;

            $typePrev = $prev['type'];
            $uploaddirPrev = "booksPreviews/";
            $namePrev = microtime().".".substr($type, strlen("image/"));
            $uploadfilePrev = $uploaddirPrev.$namePrev;   

            if(move_uploaded_file($bookPreview["tmp_name"], $uploadfilePrev)){
                if(move_uploaded_file($uploadBook["tmp_name"], $uploadfileBook)){
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `books` (`name`, `description`, `preview`, `author`, `download`) VALUES ('$bookName', '$bookDescr', '$uploadfilePrev', '$login', '$uploadfileBook');");
                }                    
            }          
        }else $errors[] = 'обложка не безопасна';
        if (!bookFunc($uploadBook)) $errors[] = 'Ошибка при загрузке книги!';        
    } else $errors[] = 'файл не безопасен';
```

на функции isSecurity не обращайте внимания.

move_uploaded_file выдает ошибку:

> move_uploaded_file(booksPreviews/0.61426800 1565946100.): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied и  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'W:\userdata\temp\phpA241.tmp' to 'booksPreviews/0.61426800
>   1565946100.'

т.е. отказано в доступе. Но почему. Точно по такому же принципу я реализовал загрузку аватарок на сайт.

в свойстве папки есть пункт атрибуты, в нем стоит галочка на только чтение, но снять ее не получается, после каждого снятия, она появляется сама[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня система виндовс 10, нашел ответы на линукс и мак

Comment: Во первых пишите относительные пути верно: `./booksPreviews/0.61426800 1565946100`
Во вторых: `if(!file_exists('./booksPreviews')) mkdir('./booksPreviews');`
В третьих проверьте права на папку "booksPreviews".
зы. относительный путь следует указывать от текущей дирректории "**./**"

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков так тоже выдает ту же самую ошибку

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков права на папку установил (свойства - доступ - расширенные настройки) полный доступ, но всё-равно не работает((((

Comment: У сервера нет прав на запись в эту папку, проверьте под каким пользователем он запускается и модифицируйте доступ для него у этой папки в дополнительных настройках безопасности и доступа.

Comment: стоят максимальные права

Answer (score 0, accepted):

УРА, у меня получилось! Я включил error_reporting(E_ALL); и оказалось, что я в формировании типа, названия использовал неверные переменные. спасибо, E_ALL